# Scala check if external process id (pid) is currently running?

Tags: java, bash, scala, process, pid

I need to check if a specified process is currently running using Scala.

All I have is the PID.

Does Scala have an internal function or do I need to parse it using `ps`?

Thank you.

Comment: or check existence of `/proc/{pid}` http://serverfault.com/questions/366474/whats-a-proper-way-of-checking-if-a-pid-is-running (not sure about scala but should be a 1 liner via regular file.exists api)

Comment: @zapl Thank you. How does this solution compare to parsing the `ps` command?

Comment: @zapl Note, that checking `/proc/{pid}` will be strictly linux solution (e.g. it won't work on osx)

Comment: @DannyBit it's easier I guess. But I don't know whether you end up with code that works on more systems either way. `ps` may not be available or have odd syntax (=parsing fail?) on some system, but the same thing could maybe happen to `/proc/{pid}` on some *nix/bsd/odd thing. The only thing I know for sure is that it works on my machine.

Comment: look at [Ammonite](http://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/#Operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Java or Scala doesn't have such functionality. If you are on UNIX based machine, yes, your best bet is to use `ps` command.

You can use the PID with `ps` command as follows:

```
ps -p 8238 -o "pid="
```

Here PID is 8283, and we ask `ps` to search for it, and if it exists, just print it.

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> def processExists(pid: Int) = pid == {try { (List("ps", "-p", s"$pid", "-o", "pid=") !!).trim.toInt } catch { case _: Throwable => -1 }}
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
processExists: (pid: Int)Boolean

scala> val pid = 8238
pid: Int = 8238

scala> processExists(pid)
res11: Boolean = true

scala> processExists(1234)
res12: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Yes I am on an Unix machine. What would the cleanest way to parse `ps` in Scala?

Comment: Check for updated answer with `def processExists(pid: Int)`

Answer (score 3):

You can import `sys.process._`

## General example

```
import sys.process._
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "ps" !

PID TTY           TIME CMD
570 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
591 ttys000    0:00.01 bash /usr/local/bin/scala
```

## getting the PID for the process scala

```
// !! to get result as String
scala> "\\d+".r.findFirstIn( "ps" #| "grep /usr/local/bin/scala" !! )
res9: Option[String] = Some(591)
```

for a more information see: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package

Answer (score 2):

When running `Scala` on `Java 9`, we can take advantage of `Java`'s [ProcessHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) which makes it easier to identify and work with native processes:

```
ProcessHandle.of(5210) match { case p => p.isPresent && p.get.isAlive }
```

where 5210 is the pid of the process you're interested in getting the status for.

This:

- First creates a Java `Optional<ProcessHandle>` from the given `pid`.
- If the process exists, this `Optional` must be `present` (which might be enough to tell if the process is alive depending on the system).
- And finally checks that the process is alive using `ProcessHandle::isAlive`.

No import necessary as `ProcessHandle` is part of `java.lang`.